# Angular testing - Cannot read property 'clear' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, jasmine, karma-runner

I have a component like below

```
   <select #tabSelect (change)="tabLoad($event.target.value)" class="mr-2">
                  <option value="tab1">First tab</option>
                  <option value="tab2">Second tab</option>
                </select>


 <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane fade show active">
          <ng-template #tabContent></ng-template>
        </div>
      </div>
```

There are two tabs,they call tabLoad() function and sends parameter what tab clicked.

```
export class DemoComponent implements OnInit {

  @ViewChild('tabContent', { read: ViewContainerRef }) entry: ViewContainerRef;
  activeTab: any = 'tab1';

  constructor(private resolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.tabLoad(this.activeTab);
  }

  tabLoad(page) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.activeTab = page;
      this.entry.clear();
      if (page == 'tab1') {
        const factory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(Tab1Component);
        console.log(this.entry);
        this.entry.createComponent(factory);
      } else if (page == 'tab2') {
        const factory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(Tab2Component);
        this.entry.createComponent(factory);
      }
    }, 500);
  }

}
```

In this .ts fle I made a variable called entry which points to #tabContent.Tab content loads a component depends on what page is active.

I wrote a test suite for this behavior like below

```
fdescribe('DemoComponent', () => {
    let component: DemoComponent;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<DemoComponent>;

    beforeEach(async(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [RouterModule.forRoot([]), SharedModule],
            declarations: [Tab1Component, Tab2Component],
        }).compileComponents().then(() => {
            fixture = TestBed.createComponent(DemoComponent);
            component = fixture.componentInstance;
        });
    }));
    it('should set activeTab correctly and clear entry when tabLoad is called', fakeAsync(() => {
        component.tabLoad("tab1");
        flush();
        expect(component.activeTab).toBe('tab1');
    }));
});
```

This test fails and says `Cannot read property 'clear' of undefined` when I call  this.entry.clear(); . Also  `console.log(this.entry);` prints undefined.
Then I decided to add `fixture.detectChanges()` on .`compileComponents().then(() => {})` scope but still fails in the same way.But when I go to the page after ng serve everything works well.

Comment: to fix current test, you need to add `fixture.detectChanges()` inside `fakeAsync`, but actually that timeout is very strange and 500 looks like magic number, why not use `ngAfterViewInit` instead

Comment: @PetrAveryanov cause I need tabload to be triggered whenever tabs are clicked.How to do that with ngAfterViewInit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first `fixture.detectChanges()` calls `ngOnInit` and you need to call it in a `fakeAsync` zone for `flush` to take effect since the `setTimeout` gets created on the `ngOnInit` call. In essence, the timer needs to be created in a `fakeAsync` zone. So try putting the `fixture.detectChanges()` inside of the test (it block) and remove it from the `.then`.

```
beforeEach(async(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [RouterModule.forRoot([]), SharedModule],
            declarations: [Tab1Component, Tab2Component],
        }).compileComponents().then(() => {
            fixture = TestBed.createComponent(DemoComponent);
            component = fixture.componentInstance;
            // !! remove fixture.detectChanges() from here
        });
    }));
    it('should set activeTab correctly and clear entry when tabLoad is called', fakeAsync(() => {
        // !! add it here
        fixture.detectChanges();
        component.tabLoad("tab1");
        flush();
        expect(component.activeTab).toBe('tab1');
    }));
```

And like `Petr` said, instead of using `500ms`, you can use `ngAfterViewInit`.

Try this:

```
export class DemoComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit { /* add AfterViewInit */

  @ViewChild('tabContent', { read: ViewContainerRef }) entry: ViewContainerRef;
  activeTab: any = 'tab1';

  constructor(private resolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.tabLoad(this.activeTab);
  }

  tabLoad(page) {
      this.activeTab = page;
      this.entry.clear();
      if (page == 'tab1') {
        const factory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(Tab1Component);
        console.log(this.entry);
        this.entry.createComponent(factory);
      } else if (page == 'tab2') {
        const factory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(Tab2Component);
        this.entry.createComponent(factory);
      }
  }

}
```

And then I don't think you would need `fakeAsync` and `flush`.